# how to fix `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and got this issue in following code. when I ran this code I get error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      monsters: [
        {
          id: '1223',
          name: 'franken'
        },
        {
          id: '145',
          name: 'dracula'
        },
        {
          id: '156',
          name: 'nosferatu'
        },
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.monsters.map(monster => {
          <h1 key={monster.id}>{monster.name}</h1>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It should show me list the of render in the browser instead it throws the following error.

```
Expected an assignment or function call but instead got an expression
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to return the component from your array `map`:

```
{this.state.monsters.map(monster => {
  return <h1 key={monster.id}>{monster.name}</h1>
})}
```